# How to make the page reload as soon as a button is clicked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, window

I want to run a javascript code where it basically reloads a page at the click of a button. I have a feeling I should start with `window.`... but I don't know how to make it reload. Please Help! I will clarify if questions come up.

Comment: `window.location.reload()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) I think you could have found this had you done a Google search.

Comment: @RyanWilson  Yes. It hadn't worked at first but now it does. I had forgotten the `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.reload()
```

The above should do the trick.

Comment: @RyanWilson Did i miss anything ?

Comment: It was my bad attempt at a joke, "the first rule of fight club..."